# Plotly Line Chart - points joint in wrong sequence

Tags: plot, plotly, linechart, plotly.js, pivottable.js

When using [Pivottable.js](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/) with [Plotly](https://plotly.com/javascript/line-charts/) Line Chart, the points were connected with vertical line. By right it should connected with horizontal line.

#### Codes to reproduce

```
<div id="output" style="overflow:scroll;width:100%"></div>
<script>
    var numberFormat = $.pivotUtilities.numberFormat;
    var floatFormat = numberFormat({digitsAfterDecimal: 1});
    var tpl = $.pivotUtilities.aggregatorTemplates; 
    var derivers = $.pivotUtilities.derivers;
    var renderers = $.extend($.pivotUtilities.renderers,
        $.pivotUtilities.plotly_renderers);   
    
    
    var months = ['2000-01','2000-01',  '2000-02', '2000-03', '2000-04', '2000-05', '2000-06', '2000-07', '2000-08', '2000-09', '2000-10', '2000-11', '2000-12', '2001-01', '2001-01'];
    var scores = [-6.5, -30.0, -26.6, -43.6, -52.3, -71.5, -81.4, -80.5, -82.2, -76, -67.3, -46.1, -35, -30, -10];
    var objs =[];
    var i = 0;
    for (m of months) {
        var obj = {};
        obj['month'] = m;
        obj['score'] = scores[i];
        obj['user'] = 'Joe';
        objs.push(obj);
        i++;
    }
    
    $('#output').pivotUI(
        objs,
            {
            renderers: renderers,
            showUI: false,
                rows: ['user'],
                cols: ['month'],
                rendererName: 'Line Chart',
                rowOrder: 'value_a_to_z', 
                colOrder: 'value_a_to_z',
            aggregators: {
                    "Score": function() { return tpl.sum(floatFormat)(['score']) }
             }, 
                rendererOptions: {
                    plotly: { 
                            xaxis: {
                                tickmode: "linear", 
                                tick0: '1999-12-15',
                                dtick: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // milliseconds 
                            }
                         
                    }
                }               
            }
    );
</script>
```

#### Expected behavior

[image]

#### Actual behavior

[image]

#### Environment

- Pivottable v2.23.0
- Plotly Basic v1.53.0
- jQuery v3.4.1
- Opera Browser v70.0:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely in `rowOrder` and `colOrder` you're setting here... Plotly plots the data in the order given, and here it looks like you're sorting the data by Y-value :)

Comment: You are right, the culprit is colOrder. I have to comment off it instead of using value_a_to_z or value_z_to_a. To my surprise, without colOrder the x-axis still sort by months in ascending order (I tested this with changing the item positions in months array).